# Types of Nested Loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a simple question. I have to find out many nested loops as possible in java. I have something like for loop and if statement inside. i know that we can do like `if{if{if{if{` something like that too. just need some more idea of more types of nested loops.

if you can write down some examples. I'll  be very glad. thank you.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        int i = 0;

        for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if(j == 1 || j == 5) {
                i = 4;
            } else {
                i = 1;
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                System.out.print("**");
            }
            System.out.println();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know how many *types* of nested loops can be written or if there's a *upper limit* for nested loops? I guess the title answers my question, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can nest as many `for`/`while` loops as you'd practically want in Java: there's no practical limit.

Java has 4 looping constructs:

- [JLS 14.14 The `for` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14)

  - [JLS 14.14.1 The basic `for` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.1)
  - [JLS 14.14.2 The enhanced `for` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2) (aka "`for-each`")
- [JLS 14.12 The `while` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.12)
- [JLS 14.13 The `do` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.13) (aka "`do-while`")

Java does not have `goto` (which isn't really needed anyway).

#### See also

- [Java Nuts and Bolts/the `for` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
- [Java language guide/`for-each` loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

---

### Examples

This is a typical example of a simple "triangle"-type nested loop, where the number of iteration of the inner loop depends on the value being iterated in the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {     // prints:
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {   // *
      System.out.print("*");       // **
   }                               // ***
   System.out.println();           // ****
}                                  // *****
```

Here's an example of a "pairing"-type nested loop, where the two loops are independent of each other, using the for-each construct:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };                       // prints:  // if swapped:
char[] letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };                // 1 A      // 1 A
                                                   // 1 B      // 2 A
for (int number : numbers) {                       // 1 C      // 3 A
   for (char letter : letters) {                   // 2 A      // 1 B
       System.out.println(number + " " + letter);  // 2 B      // 2 B
   }                                               // 2 C      // 3 B
}                                                  // 3 A      // 1 C
                                                   // 3 B      // 2 C
                                                   // 3 C      // 3 C
```

The `for-each` construct, which lacks explicit indices, makes the indepedence of both loops obvious: you can swap the two `for` statements in the above code, and you'd still get all pairs, though listed in a different order.

This use of a `boolean` method for a `while` loop (this one from [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)) is typical:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("here we go again");     // prints:
while (sc.hasNext()) {                            // hereeeee
   String s = sc.next();                          // weeeee
   char lastChar = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);      // gooooo
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                  // againnnnn
      s += lastChar;
   }
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

And here's an example that shows how `do-while` is different from `while-do` and `for`:

```
    int x = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Hello!!!");
    } while (x != 0);
```

The above loop prints `Hello!!!`: the body of a `do-while` is executed before the termination condition is checked.

---

### A more elaborate example

Here's an example of a nested-loop logic, but refactored into methods to make things more readable. This is something that is important for beginners to learn: **just because you can physically nest loops as many levels as you want, doesn't mean you should**. By breaking apart the logic like this, the program becomes more modular and readable, and each logic stands on its own and can be tested and reused, etc.

This snippet reverses the letters of a word in a `char[]` in-place.

```
static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
static void reverse(char[] arr, int from, int to) {
    int N = (to - from);
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
        swap(arr, from+i, to-1-i);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] sentence = "reversing letters of words in sentence".toCharArray();
    final int L = sentence.length;
    int last = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++) {
        if ((i == L) || (sentence[i] == ' ')) {
            reverse(sentence, last, i);
            last = i + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(new String(sentence));
    // prints "gnisrever srettel fo sdrow ni ecnetnes"
}
```

This example is also instructive in that **even though it's essentially a nested loop algorithm, it's actually** `O(N)`! It's a mistake to think that any doubly nested-loop algorithm must be `O(N^2)` -- it really depends on the algorithm itself more than just the physical structure.

---

### Nested-loop Algorithms

These are classical algorithms traditionally implemented using nested loops (at least in their naive forms):

- `O(N^2)` Sorting algorithms:

  - [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)
  - [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)
  - [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)
- `O(N^3)` triply nested loop algorithms:

  - [Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)
- Table-filling dynamic programming algorithms

  - [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (`O(N^2)`, string edit distance)
  - [Floyd-Warshall Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) (`O(N^3)`, all-pairs shortest path in graph)

These are far from an exhaustive sampling, but it should provide a good introduction to a variety of nested `for` loops algorithms for beginners.

Comment: thank you very much. the reason I am asking you this was I have to group book project about nested loop. I wanted to show many many types of nested loops as possible.  so, while, for, if are the only things we can use??

Comment: @dominoos: are you asking how many control structures there are in Java? Because that's an entirely different question.

Comment: I was asking for examples of nested loops. and I wanted to show verities of nested loops.

Comment: @dominoos: I can't be doing your group book project for you. I've done all I can here, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The code `if { if { if { ... } } }` is not an example of nested loops. `if` does not use loop.

Looping expressions are for example `for` and `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Loops can be done using the 3 basic loop statements: `for`, `while` and `do..while`. 
However, if your question is about how many *types* of nested loops are possible in Java, I'd say *LOTS*, since you can arrange and mix them as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I like the previous answer, but in an attempt to answer directly this curious question:

`if-else` is not a loop type. Java has `for`, `while`, and `do-while` loops. You could argue the the "foreach" syntax for `for` loops, introduced in Java 5, is a different kind of loop for your purpose. But really it is just shorthand for writing a while loop.

But all of these "different" loop types are just language constructs. In the byte code that is compiled, they're not intrinsically different.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the compiler. I wrote a simple test program that generates Java files with different levels of loop nesting.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class NestingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        for (int n = 1; n < 10000; ++n)
        {
            String className = "test" + n;
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("f:/test/" + className + ".java");
            BufferedWriter o = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            o.write("public class ");
            o.write(className);
            o.write("\n{\npublic static void main(String[] args) {\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                o.write("while(true) {\n");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                o.write("}\n");
            }
            o.write("}\n}\n");
            o.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Once the files are generated, you do a manual binary search. Compile test5000. If it succeeds, compile test7500, and if it doesn't, compile test2500. After 13 or 14 steps, you should come to a conclusion.

My compiler's sweetspot seems to be 5345 levels of nesting for this simple program, so I guess in practice it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, nesting has no limit.

Comment: Actually, there is a theoretical limit in that a single class can only have 64K bytes of bytecodes.  But in practice, you are unlikely to reach that limit by simply nesting loops.